# Remove the last 0 in a list of vectors if it appears twice at the end

Tags: r, list

I have data as follows:

```
dat <- list(`A` = c(0, 25, 500, 1000, 0, 0), `B` = c(0, 
25, 500, 1000, 1500, 0)
```

I would like to remove the last `0` if there are two `0`'s.

I am breaking my brain on how to achieve this but I cannot come up with anything.

How should I do this?

Desired output:

```
out_dat <- list(`A` = c(0, 25, 500, 1000, 0), `B` = c(0, 
25, 500, 1000, 1500, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
trim0 <- function (x) {
  if (all(tail(x, 2) == 0)) x[-length(x)] else x
}

out_dat <- lapply(dat, trim0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
lapply(dat, function(x) x[c(TRUE, !x[-length(x)] == x[-1])])
```

Output:

```
$A
[1]    0   25  500 1000    0

$B
[1]    0   25  500 1000 1500    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lapply(dat , \(x) if(rev(x)[1] == rev(x)[2] & rev(x)[1] == 0) x[1:(length(x) - 1)] else x)
```

- output

```
$A
[1]    0   25  500 1000    0

$B
[1]    0   25  500 1000 1500    0
```